# Com.Google.Common.*.*... import failure

Tags: java, import

I'm working on a project and need to use the Predicate interface of google's common.base
I tried importing the google-collect jar at http://code.google.com/p/gdata-java-client/source/browse/#svn/trunk/java/deps

I got the jar, imported it in my library but nothing's there...
Can anyone tell help me to be able to work with this interface?

Comment: you are not giving enough information.

Comment: if we are to judge by the question title, you are using the wrong letter case for imports. But show your code.

Comment: We need your code, we need to know if you are using an IDE, your project structure, etc.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using eclipse, you need to add the library jar to your build path, as described [here](http://www.javahotchocolate.com/tutorials/jars.html#buildpath).

If you are compiling from the command line, use the [`-classpath` option](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/tooldocs/win32/javac.html#options) to add the jar to the path.

Also make sure the case is correct in your import declaration.  The import should look like

> `import com.google.common.base.Predicate;`

**not**

> <s>`import Com.Google.Common.Base.Predicate;`</s>

Also you probably know this already, but the import `com.google.common.*.*` suggested by your question title is invalid - you can only have one `*`.  (`import com.google.common.base.*` is OK.)